# Snort dynamic engine issues on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, snort

I can't seem to find the answer to this issue.  A lot of topics exist for similar errors but they are all Linux based.

The issue I'm having is that when attempting to run Snort (snort.exe -v -I), it will capture nothing but I assume this is because I have not set an interface.  After running *snort.exe -W*, I found the interface to use and specified this in the command line but I get the following error - **ERROR: Can't set DAQ BPF filter to '2'**.

I skipped past this error briefly to try and test Snort with -T and -c to specify the config file but it gives the following error - **Missing/incorrect dynamic engine lib specifier**.  I located this line in the config file and changed it from **/usr/local/snort_dynamicengine/libsf_engine.so** to **c:\Snort\lib\snort_dynamicengine\sf_engine.dll** (the correct path and file name) but the error remains.

I remember installing Snort on a Windows Server 2012 deployment a couple of months back with no issues at all.

Any idea what is causing this error?

NOTE: I've also corrected the other paths i.e. rules.

Answer (score 4):

I just had also the Problem, and solve it delete a single /

```
ERROR:: c:\snort\etc\snort.conf (246) Missing/incorrect dynamic engine lib specifie.
```

So i edit:

```
dynamicpreprocessor directory c:\snort\lib\snort_dynamicpreprocessor\ <---*
```

**This "\" was wrong**

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer is late, but still, I just ran into this issue and I think a valid answer should be provided. Anyways, the problem is based on paths, all of the snort.conf file are paths relative to linux specific locations. So that's problem number one, the second problem comes with snort parsing whatever path you give it in the -c option and prepending it to all the rules path (I know, weird) this should not happen if you (and most windows users) use absolute paths. So the solution I came up with is:

**PLEASE NOTE,** every single path is wrong, the following snippet only helps you to advance one step, after this, you need to correct all the file paths.

In your snort.conf file (usually c:\snort\etc\snort.conf)

```
###################################################
# Step #4: Configure dynamic loaded libraries.  
# For more information, see Snort Manual, Configuring Snort - Dynamic Modules
###################################################

# path to dynamic preprocessor libraries
dynamicpreprocessor directory C:\Snort\lib\snort_dynamicpreprocessor

# path to base preprocessor engine
dynamicengine C:\Snort\lib\snort_dynamicengine\sf_engine.dll

# path to dynamic rules libraries
# dynamicdetection directory /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicrules
```

Answer (score 0):

**Rule to Remember**

Always use a proper text editor to edit config file like [this](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/fr/) because some time when you copy and paste code in notepad and edit so some extra spaces added into the text which cause increase in bytes or altering the code statements.
Good thing is some editors provide proper line number so you can easily navigate to the error show by snort in command prompt.

**Solution**

In My Scenario

[image]

due to this

[image]

this is because some spaces were added after

> leaving the code statement on the next line which is not correct and
> this will be read during execution of snort because this IS NO LONGER A COMMENT since >you took it out from comment section  which is  marked as **#** (per line)this is due to white spaces added when you copy and paste code in some poor editors.

**After Removing white space**

[image]

[image]

**Finally dynamic engine line should look like this to make it work**

[image]

Comment: The important piece this showed me is that I had to remove a trailing slash off of the synamicpreprocessors directory statement.  Which is odd because the default Linux based path has a trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the correct content of step 4 for any Microsoft Windows 7+ OS should look like this (adapt the absolute paths, if necessary):

```
###################################################
# Step #4: Configure dynamic loaded libraries.
# For more information, see Snort Manual, Configuring Snort - Dynamic Modules
###################################################

# path to dynamic preprocessor libraries
# dynamicpreprocessor directory /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor/
dynamicpreprocessor directory C:\snort\lib\snort_dynamicpreprocessor

# path to base preprocessor engine
# dynamicengine /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicengine/libsf_engine.so
dynamicengine C:\snort\lib\snort_dynamicengine\sf_engine.dll

# path to dynamic rules libraries
# dynamicdetection directory /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicrules
# dynamicdetection directory C:\snort\lib\snort_dynamicrules (# under Microsoft Windows)
```

Also mind correct values for:

- HOME_NET (e. g. `ipvar HOME_NET 192.168.1.1/24` or `ipvar HOME_NET 192.168.0.0/16` or, basically, `ipvar HOME_NET any`)
- EXTERNAL_NET (some suggest `ipvar EXTERNAL_NET !$HOST_NET` which does not work with me, so I left that at `ipvar EXTERNAL_NET any`)

Additionally, whitelist and blacklist directories have to be defined:

```
# If you are using reputation preprocessor set these
# Currently there is a bug with relative paths, they are relative to where snort is
# not relative to snort.conf like the above variables
# This is completely inconsistent with how other vars work, BUG 89986
# Set the absolute path appropriately
# var WHITE_LIST_PATH ../rules
var WHITE_LIST_PATH C:\snort\whitelist_rules
# var BLACK_LIST_PATH ../rules
var BLACK_LIST_PATH C:\snort\blacklist_rules
```

Mind that you have to `mkdir` these directories yourself.

Additionally, you need to define (even empty) files in these directories:

```
touch C:\snort\whitelist_rules\white_list.rules
touch C:\snort\blacklist_rules\black_list.rules
```

Whereas it seems you can name arbitrary directory names, the files' name must correspond to the mentioned `white_list.rules` and `black_list.rules` (mind the underscores).

Personally, the best and most inspirational "HOWTO" for me has been this post:

https://www.securityarchitecture.com/learning/intrusion-detection-systems-learning-with-snort/configuring-snort/

My snort invoking string (from a batch file) looks like this: `snort.exe -A console -i 15 -c C:\snort\etc\snort.conf -l C:\snort\log -K pcap`. `-K pcap` determines an output format which can be imported by Wireshark and, thus, further analysed. `-i 15` is specific for my setting (15 = Wi-Fi) - check that out using `snort.exe -W` under Microsoft Windows and `snort -w` under Linux.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of you **wont like my advice** but please *dont try snort in windows* as it lead me to a rabbit hole of errors. In windows this guys(the snort company) didnt use the slash path properly and I had to comment out many other things and a lot of files and directories were missing too

Comment: I just checked out snort in my friends ubuntu computer and he has all the files and path properly listed in there.